# Rails raw SQL example

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How can I convert this code to raw sql and use in rails? Because When I deploy this code in heroku,there is a request timeout error.I think this will be faster if I use raw sql.

```
@payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project).order('payment_details.created_at desc')
@payment_errors = PaymentError.joins(:project).order('payment_errors.created_at desc')

@all_payments = (@payments + @payment_errors)
```

Comment: Why do you think raw SQL will be faster?  How do you know its a SQL issue?

Comment: Without seeing the query plan I would guess that the issue you are having is ordering by created_at. You are probably doing a seq scan across those entire tables (oh and bringing in the project table too). Doing two of those in once controller method on a big table and underpowered DB (heroku databases are tuned generically, and relatively underpowered for the $$ you spend) you are likely to get timeouts. If you aren't doing a lot of inserts into these tables you could do a sorted index: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#sorted-indexes

Comment: Well it would always be faster to hand cut the sql (if you know what you're doing).  Rails makes some really nasty sql.  It works well but to be general it has to... be general.  That said Jim is likely right.. creating indexing would be better.  Try running your query in pgadmin (against your db)

Answer (score 569, accepted):

You can do this:

```rb
sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

`records_array` would then be the result of your sql query in an array which you can iterate through.

Comment: side note: `records_array` will be of different types for different database adapters. If you're using PG, it will be an instance of `PG::Result`, not `Array`.

Comment: and then you'd need to call `values` on this `PG::Result` object to get the results array

Comment: @baash05 What do you mean by "in favour of accessing it via the class." - this talks about how to access the table without a model ariond it

Comment: Actually there's no mention of not using a model in the OP.  Just how to execute raw sql.   PaymentDetail.execute(sql) works.

Comment: You can answer my question, as I had the same problem and went here  for the solution. Question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626194/active-record-insert-into

Comment: call `.as_json` for an array of hashes in from `PG::Result`

Comment: I like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` better because it returns an `ActiveRecords::Result` object which has handy methods like `.columns` and `.rows` to access headers and values. The array of hashes from `.execute` can be troublesome to deal with and gave me redundant results when I ran with a SUM GROUP BY clause.

Comment: In case of PG the returned instance is `PG::Result` and you can use `to_a` to convert it to array

Answer (score 243):

I know this is old... But I was having the same problem today and found a solution:

```
Model.find_by_sql
```

If you want to instantiate the results:

```
Client.find_by_sql("
  SELECT * FROM clients
  INNER JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
  ORDER BY clients.created_at desc
")
# => [<Client id: 1, first_name: "Lucas" >, <Client id: 2, first_name: "Jan">...]
```

---

```
Model.connection.select_all('sql').to_hash
```

If you just want a hash of values:

```
Client.connection.select_all("SELECT first_name, created_at FROM clients
   WHERE id = '1'").to_hash
# => [
  {"first_name"=>"Rafael", "created_at"=>"2012-11-10 23:23:45.281189"},
  {"first_name"=>"Eileen", "created_at"=>"2013-12-09 11:22:35.221282"}
]
```

Result object:

`select_all` returns a `result` object. You can do magic things with it.

```
result = Post.connection.select_all('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')
# Get the column names of the result:
result.columns
# => ["id", "title", "body"]

# Get the record values of the result:
result.rows
# => [[1, "title_1", "body_1"],
      [2, "title_2", "body_2"],
      ...
     ]

# Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value):
result.to_hash
# => [{"id" => 1, "title" => "title_1", "body" => "body_1"},
      {"id" => 2, "title" => "title_2", "body" => "body_2"},
      ...
     ]

# ActiveRecord::Result also includes Enumerable.
result.each do |row|
  puts row['title'] + " " + row['body']
end
```

Sources:

1. [ActiveRecord -  Findinig by
   SQL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql).
2. [Ruby on Rails -  Active Record Result](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html)
   .

Comment: `#find_by_sql` is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much.

Comment: #find_by_sql is it!!

Answer (score 46):

You can execute raw query using `ActiveRecord`. And I will suggest to go with SQL block

```
query = <<-SQL 
  SELECT * 
  FROM payment_details
  INNER JOIN projects 
          ON projects.id = payment_details.project_id
  ORDER BY payment_details.created_at DESC
SQL

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: Hi.. is there any way to pass parameters to this query?

Comment: @AkshayGoyal you can use normal ruby string interpolation within the block. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = #{ user.id }`

Comment: While you can do that it may expose you to the possibility of SQL injection

Comment: Works for updates, thanks!

Answer (score 30):

You can do direct SQL to have a single query for both tables. I'll provide a sanitized query example to hopefully keep people from putting variables directly into the string itself (SQL injection danger), even though this example didn't specify the need for it:

```
@results = []
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, 
   ["... your SQL query goes here and ?, ?, ? are replaced...;", a, b, c])
).each do |record|
  # instead of an array of hashes, you could put in a custom object with attributes
  @results << {col_a_name: record["col_a_name"], col_b_name: record["col_b_name"], ...}
end
```

*Edit*: as Huy said, a simple way is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("...")`. Another way is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('...').rows`. And you can use native prepared statements, e.g. if using postgres, prepared statement can be done with raw_connection, prepare, and exec_prepared as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806512/178651

You can also put raw SQL fragments into ActiveRecord relational queries: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
and in associations, scopes, etc. You could probably construct the same SQL with ActiveRecord relational queries and can do cool things with ARel as Ernie mentions in http://erniemiller.org/2010/03/28/advanced-activerecord-3-queries-with-arel/. And, of course there are other ORMs, gems, etc.

If this is going to be used a lot and adding indices won't cause other performance/resource issues, consider adding an index in the DB for payment_details.created_at and for payment_errors.created_at.

If lots of records and not all records need to show up at once, consider using pagination:

- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pagination
- https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

If you need to paginate, consider creating a view in the DB first called payment_records which combines the payment_details and payment_errors tables, then have a model for the view (which will be read-only). Some DBs support materialized views, which might be a good idea for performance.

Also consider hardware or VM specs on Rails server and DB server, config, disk space, network speed/latency/etc., proximity, etc. And consider putting DB on different server/VM than the Rails app if you haven't, etc.

Comment: Since the asker is sorting by date I think pagination wouldn't help? I'm not the deepest on SQL but my understanding is the query in the original post would need to fetch the entire table in order to sort it - only then could it limit the results. I suspect the bulk of the query plan is in the order clause.

Comment: @JimWrubel clarified the paragraph on pagination- the wording was a little out of sorts.

Answer (score 17):

I want to work with `exec_query` of the `ActiveRecord` class, because it returns the mapping of the query transforming into object, so it gets very practical and productive to iterate with the objects when the subject is Raw SQL.

Example:

```
values = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("select * from clients")
p values
```

and return this complete query:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "user 1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "user 2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "user 3"}]
```

To get only list of values

```
p values.rows

[[1, "user 1"], [2, "user 2"], [3, "user 3"]]
```

To get only fields columns

```
p values.columns

["id", "name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also mix raw SQL with ActiveRecord conditions, for example if you want to call a function in a condition:

```
my_instances = MyModel.where.not(attribute_a: nil)
  .where('crc32(attribute_b) = ?', slot)
  .select(:id)
```