# how to query SQL in rails step by step?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been looking on online everywhere for an answer with no luck. Where do I enter my query? In rails c? I know i must use ActiveRecord::base.connection but I am clueless where it must be run. Sorry if this is a foolish question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails uses an ORM called ActiveRecord to interface with SQL databases:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

The syntax is straight-forward and you can enter queries by opening up your rails console with `rails console` (abbreviated `rails c`).

For example, if I want to find all of the records in the Question table, I open my console and simply type `Question.all`:

`irb(main):001:0> Question.all`

...which translates to the following SQL query:

`Question Load (4.2ms)  SELECT 'questions'.* FROM 'questions'`

If you want to execute raw SQL commands in the rails console, you would use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(some_string)` with the SQL as a string object.

You could write the SQL string as the argument directly or declare it beforehand as a variable:

```
sql = "some raw sql"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Check out this question for more: [Rails raw SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example)

Comment: So this means that if I need to enter an active record statement it would be ActiveRecord::base.execute (statement) ? What if it's a complex query? Is there a file I wrote down everything on and then load it on rails console?

Comment: ah, I see. At first I didn't get that you want to execute raw SQL. In that case, you just use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_as_string). I will update my answer.