# Rails : export large model data as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to export a table which has over 100,000 rows

```
def export  
  export_data = []
  MyModel.uncached do
    MyModel.find_each do |s|
      export_data << {
        :col1 => s.col1,
        :col2 => s.col2,
        :col3 => s.col3,
        :col4 => s.col4
      }
    end
  end
  export_data = {:export_data => export_data }
  send_data export_data.to_json, :type => :json, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => "export_data.json"
end
```

When I hit this action using a url_path it is taking very long time to process the request and also the file downloaded is around 80MB.

What is the proper way to approach this problem so that the user need not wait for the request to complete?

Comment: You can send that file to user in a mail instead of making the user to wait for request to end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make raw sql query: [Rails raw SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example)
2. Convert returned value to json.

Another way is tools like [this](http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json). Just google something similar