# Rails - has_many :through find records which have no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :people, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I'm using a attribute called 'kind' on the Assignment model to determine how the person is associated with the property.  It's a string field and possible values include: 'supervisor', 'worker', 'inspector'.

I've added the attribute to the Assignment model rather than the Person model because in some scenarios its possible for a person to be a worker on one project, and a supervisor on another at the same time.

Its important to note, that when created a supervisor is automatically assigned.  Therefore all projects will have at least one assignment already.

What I'm wondering is this:

How do I query all projects which have no workers assigned?  This would be a project which has no assignments which have 'worker' in the kind column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord's [joins](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) query method to accomplish this.

```
Project.joins(:assignments).where('assignments.kind <> ?', 'worker')
```

This will result in the following query

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "assignments"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE (assignments.kind <> 'worker')
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for this great answer.  Interestingly "<>" didn't function as desired, whereas "!=" did. I changed it to:  `Project.joins(:assignments).where('assignments.kind != ?', 'worker')`

Comment: No problem. That's interesting about `<>`, what DB are you using?

Comment: Odd indeed since in Postgres `<>` and `!=` are the same. [Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html)

Answer (score 1):

To be efficient you could use a counter_cache column.

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
end

Project.where(assigments_count: 0)
```

Check the counter_cache part in: [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
And note that you will need to reset counter cache column on already created models.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use SQL if you want to avoid extra columns and db updates [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another) + [rails raw sql example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example)