# Ruby On Rails & Interacting with the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

How can I write SQL queries for CRUD if I don't want to use the constructors & ghost methods' concept of the Rails.
Eg. What if i want to INSERT INTO  Values()
instead of using Tablename.create()...and the saving it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14824453/438992

Comment: But... why?! Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL queries with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.

```
sql = <<-eos
  INSERT INTO table_name
  VALUES (1, 2, 3);
eos
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

However, besides performing [mass insertions of many rows at once](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) there rarely is a good reason to do an insert with raw SQL. Your giving up all the goodies that come with Rails and ActiveRecord such as SQL injection protection, validations etc.

Comment: (Clearly a dupe as the link I provided shows; in general it's better to mark as a dupe than dupe an answer :)