# How do I write this SQL into Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to get the **sequence** for the id column in the tags table as

```
 SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence(‘tags’, ‘id’);
```

And then I want to use the result from the above Query (the sequence) as an input to the second query. Let s say the first query is called **sequence**
I want to perform the second query as:

```
 SELECT setval(**sequence**, SELECT max(id) FROM tags);
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14824453/720164

Comment: Thanks, it helps part of it

Comment: I figure it's just a matter of running the first query on a generic AR connection, then take the result, and insert it into another query.

Comment: BTW try the single query: `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(‘tags’, ‘id’), SELECT max(id) FROM tags);`

Comment: Would that work inside a ".rb" file ?

Comment: Let s say inside my seeds.rb ?

Comment: @Abelisto looks like that SQL is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("your SQL query here").