# SQL + Rails - is it posible to get a collection of objects with the values of attributes from other table columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Baby
  belongs_to :child
  attr :is_public
  scope :public, includes(:child).merge(Child.public).where('babies.is_public IS TRUE')
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  attr :is_public

  scope: public, where ???
  def is_public; read_attribute(:is_public).blank? ? self.parent.is_public : super(); end
end

class Parent
  has_many :children
  attr :is_public
end
```

Is it possible to get a collection of objects of Child 
  where if the value of attribute_a of child is NULL 
  it should get the value from parents.attribute_a 
in one sql statement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14840547/3523538

Answer (score 0):

> I think, basic SQL logic should by like this:

```
SELECT c.*,p.* FROM child c
INNER JOIN parent p ON p.id = c.parent_id
LEFT JOIN baby b on b.id = c.baby_id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

> if you want to use SQL query instead of ruby class, you can use:

```
query_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('Your query')
```

Hope this helps