# Executing raw sql against multiple data bases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sqlite, activerecord

This is a followup to 
[executing raw sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example). I am working on a project where I need to stream in information form multiple databases. How would I do something similar to

```
sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

but have support for choosing the connection??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` to switch database connection. Code should be like this:

```
#database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: development_db

development_another_db:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: another_db


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development_another_db
sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development
sql = "Another select"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

You may find details about `establish_connection` in [Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class).

Comment: Can this be done across connections to select from one database and insert into another?

Comment: @SawyerMerchant, Yes, definitely. Since `sql` here is just a plain string without any relation to database connection or active record.