# Getting syntax error when using raw SQL SELECT command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am not sure why I am getting the syntax error, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example) everything should be okay. I could not find a way to execute a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) (postgres query which returns multiple columns **GROUPED BY** an **individual** column) that is the reason why I used raw SQL.

I am still new to Postgres, but I gathered that it may have to do with sanitization, but I do not know how to go about that either. Any help will be greatly appreciated, here is my code:

```
module TasksTestQuery

  def self.call

    query = "SELECT user_id, username, date, SUM(user_id) AS total_work, SUM(duration) AS total_duration OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) FROM tasks"

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.find_by_sql(query)

  end
end
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: SELECT user_id, username, date, SUM(user_id) AS total_work, SUM(duration) AS total_duration OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) FROM tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
SUM(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS total_duration
```

Comment: Mistake was on my side, this solved it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion