# Multiple records as result of inner join on array values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two tables in Postgres:

```
events (id, occurrence_dates) # occurrence_dates is array
dates_calendar (date)
```

When `events.occurrence_dates` consists of a few equal values, `{"2017-11-08 00:00:00","2017-11-08 00:00:00"}` 2 values as example, following query gives a single record:

```
SELECT "events".* 
FROM "events" 
   INNER JOIN dates_calendar dc ON dc.date = ALL(occurrence_dates)
```

How to get as many records as length of `events.occurrence_dates`?

UPD: i'm using Ruby on Rails, but question is provided in SQL context

Rails scope based on @michel.milezzi answer:

```
scope :all_events, -> do
  select("events_sb.*").from(<<-SQL.squish)
    dates_calendar dc
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, UNNEST(occurrence_dates) oc_date FROM events) AS events_sb
    ON (events_sb.oc_date = dc.date)
  SQL
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UNNEST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to expand the array and then use a regular join:

```
-- CTE with test data
WITH dates_calendar(date) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('2017-11-08 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP), 
        ('2017-11-09 00:00:00'), 
        ('2017-11-10 00:00:00')
), events (id, occurrence_dates) AS (
    VALUES
        (1, '{"2017-11-08 00:00:00", "2017-11-08 00:00:00","2017-11-09 00:00:00","2017-11-10 00:00:00"}'::TIMESTAMP[]), 
        (2, '{"2017-11-08 00:00:00","2017-11-09 00:00:00"}'), 
        (3, '{"2017-11-08 00:00:00"}')
), events_sb AS (
    SELECT id, UNNEST(occurrence_dates) oc_date FROM events
)
SELECT 
    events_sb.* 
FROM 
    dates_calendar dc JOIN events_sb ON (events_sb.oc_date = dc.date) ORDER BY id;

--CTE
WITH events_sb AS (
    SELECT id, UNNEST(occurrence_dates) oc_date FROM events
)
SELECT 
    events_sb.* 
FROM 
    dates_calendar dc JOIN events_sb ON (events_sb.oc_date = dc.date) ORDER BY id;    

--SUBQUERY
SELECT 
    events_sb.* 
FROM 
    dates_calendar dc JOIN (SELECT id, UNNEST(occurrence_dates) oc_date FROM events) AS events_sb ON (events_sb.oc_date = dc.date) ORDER BY id;
```

To call it in Rails you must do a plain sql, such explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840547/7925366).

Comment: thanks! Though i didn't figured out how to use it with ActiveRecord (Ruby on Rails), the idea works well with raw SQL.

WITH events_sb AS (
  SELECT *, UNNEST(occurrence_dates) oc_date  FROM EVENTS
)
SELECT events_sb.*
FROM dates_calendar dc
JOIN events_sb ON (events_sb.oc_date = dc.date);

Comment: @yurko You must create a [plain select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840547/7925366).

Comment: Why this answer was downvoted? Please comment explaining so we can discuss about it.

Comment: because of hardcoded dates in example. later I tried your query without test data and it worked, but I was not able to cancel downvote  before edit is accepted. thanx, upvoted now

Comment: No problem, glad to help you @yurko

Answer (score 0):

Is occurrence_dates a json data type? If yes, you could simply use the [json_populate_recordset()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function.

Comment: no, it is array `default '{}'::timestamp without time zone[]`