# Run a raw sql query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, pg

The following query runs fine on a postgres client (postico):

```
sql = "select rs.created_at, lv.id
from external_verification_responses rs
inner join external_verification_requests rq on rs.external_verification_request_id = rq.id
inner join leave_verifications lv on lv.id = rq.request_id
WHERE (rs.params#>>'{last_call_Trip Enquiry_1, outcome}' = 'Interested') AND (date(rs.created_at) >= '2018-08-21')
ORDER BY rs.created_at DESC"
```

However, with rails, it breaks

```
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

The error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select rs"
LINE 1: select rs.created_at, lv.id from external_verification_respo...
```

If defining alias is a problem in rails raw sql query, then how do I define alias in my query?

Comment: Well, you have a syntax error. Can you post exactly the commands you're using? Where you define `sql`. If that's the first one, then please format it properly to be valid ruby syntax (quotes and so)

Comment: sql is ofcourse a string with double quotes. I have edited in the question. However, i 'm still getting error

Comment: What's the `rs.params#>>'{last_call_Trip Enquiry_1, outcome}'` part? Also, did you try removing the alias and using `external_verification_responses.created_at` instead?

Comment: To diagnose it would you mind to try it with `sql = "select rs.created_at from external_verification_responses rs limit 1"`?

Comment: Please refer the link
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example>. U will find solution.

Comment: @dgilperez this part is json query, as said it runs fine on sql clients. I also tried without alias but same error

Comment: @mudasobwa This short sql works, however breaks on inner join

Comment: @LavanyaAnanya how is the linked answer relevant?

Comment: GUYS, as it turns out, there could have been a special character impersonating space character in the query as I was copying the query directly from sql client(postico) into rails console. When I typed the query all by myself it worked. Thanks for your support