# Return table with multiple COUNT from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 2 tables: `Client` and `Document`

A `client` has many `documents`

| Client |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Document |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| expiration_date |
| client_id |

**expiration_date format is YYYY-MM-DD**

And I want to return a table like this:

| id | name | documents_count | expired | 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | client a | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | client b | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | client c | 13 | 0 | 10 |

Right now my code is like this:

```
Client.all.left_joins(:documents).group(:id).select('clients.*, COUNT(documents.id) AS documents_count')
```

And I am missing the last 2 columns.

How can I get those 2 columns?

I tried:

```
Client.all.left_joins(:documents).group(:id).select("clients.*, COUNT(documents.id) AS documents_count, COUNT(documents.expiration < #{Date.today}) AS expired")
```

but the expired columns return booleans and not a number.

| id | name | documents_count | expired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | client a | 10 | true |
| 2 | client b | 8 | true |
| 3 | client c | 13 | true |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE client (
    id bigint,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE document (
    id bigint,
    name text,
    expiration_date date,
    client_id int
);
INSERT INTO client
SELECT
    i,
    'client_' || i
FROM
    generate_series(1, 5) _ (i);
INSERT INTO document (id, name)
SELECT
    i,
    'document' || i
FROM
    generate_series(1, 5) _ (i),
    generate_series(1, 3, 1);
COMMIT;

UPDATE
    document
SET
    client_id = (4 * random())::int + 1;

UPDATE
    document
SET
    expiration_date = (date '2022-10-25' + (random() * 30)::int);
```

query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    count(expiration_date) FILTER (WHERE expiration_date > CURRENT_DATE -30) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id) AS count_last_month,
    count(expiration_date) FILTER (WHERE expiration_date > CURRENT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id) AS count_expire
FROM
    client c
    LEFT JOIN document d ON d.id = c.id
ORDER BY
    c.id;
```

or a simple one.

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    count(expiration_date) FILTER (WHERE expiration_date > CURRENT_DATE -30) AS count_last_month,
    count(expiration_date) FILTER (WHERE expiration_date > CURRENT_DATE) AS count_expire
FROM
    client c
    LEFT JOIN document d ON d.id = c.id
GROUP BY
    1,
    2
ORDER BY
    c.id;
```

I don't know ruby, but from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example) post, I think you can run pure sql query.